# How to allow an empty TDBEdit when the field has an EditMask?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, input-mask

I have set this `TEditMask`:

```
DateTimeField.EditMask := '!99/99/9999;1; ';
```

I have a `TDBEdit` which is linked to this field.

The mask works for valid dates, but when the user tries to clear the input value (using the `DEL` key) it will cause an `EConvertError` when leaving the mask.

How to change this behavior to clear the field value instead?

Comment: Clear the underlying field instead. `DateTimeField.Clear`. I usually provide a button to clear such fields (such as the one in `TButtonedEdit` or one we've written in house to be DB-aware, but a normal TButton or TSpeedButton would work as well).

Comment: That's a nice workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution using the `OnSetText` event of the field:

```
procedure TForm1.DateTimeFieldSetText(Field: TField; const Text: string);
begin
  // This only works for locales where the date separator is '.'
  if Text = '  .  .    ' then
    Field.AsString := ''
  else
    Field.AsString := Text
end;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can test the edit text against an empty mask in an `OnSetText` event handler of the underlying data field, and set the field value only if there's no match.

```
procedure TForm1.DataTimeFieldSetText(Sender: TField; const Text: string);
begin
  if not (maskutils.FormatMaskText(Sender.EditMask, '') = Text) then
    Sender.AsString := Text;
end;
```

You don't have to know the edit mask or specific locale information.